# Setting up Universal Link in external URL

Tags: ios, ios-universal-links

we are setting up universal link on iOS 10; our target is to open an APP by clicking a link on safari.

Currently universal links are working when we are clicking a link in "Slack" (for instance); in this case the app is opened up properly.
I have read in internet that in safari universal links work only if a link is provided to a different domain.

So, I am trying to create this scenario: from site A (like http://my.first-site.com/alfa) , user clicks a link to site B (like http://my.other-site.com/beta). It is not working.

File "apple-app-site-association" is only in site A and its content is the following:

```
{
"applinks": {
    "apps": [],
    "details": [
        {
            "appID": "XXXX.mmmm",
            "paths": [
                "/beta"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
}
```

Is it enough to put the relative url "beta" ? Do I have to add the full url ? Is there any "special" arrangement in order to add an absolute url ?

Thanks

Comment: It's an old repo, but might be helpful
https://github.com/Satish/iOS-Universal-Links

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to host apple-app-site-association at http://my.other-site.com/ domain too (ie. http://my.other-site.com/apple-app-site-association).

Without this its impossible to open the app with http://my.other-site.com/beta link(s)

Actually, with this, they also identify that you own that domain and wants to open **XXXX.mmmm** app with links to the mentioned domain (ie. http://my.other-site.com/beta)